# Integration Testing CakePHP 3

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am doing Integration testing in CakePHP 3 following is Unit Test Function.

```
public function testlogin()
    {
        $this->post('/users/login', ['username' => 'test', 'password' => 'test']);

        $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    }
```

When I run Unit Test then it gives me 'No location header set' and TestCase is failing.

so I don't know which header I have to set.

Anyone Tell me which header I have to set here?

Comment: Like error message says, the `Location` header, ie your controller action needs to issue a redirect, which it doesn't seem to do for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the action does not do any redirect.
So 'No location header is set'.

Try to debug de method you are trying to test,
then verify if it does redirect to anything.

:)